# Crop Text in a td CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, crop

I'm active on a side called My Anime List. It's for tracking your Anime.
On this site you can upload a custom CSS Design für your List I already achieved the design I want, but I want to improve it little by little so my first problem occurred.

I want to to crop the Animes Names, to fit everything in one row.

How can I crop it? All I know its sth about the table layout, I already made it fixed, but now I don't know how to proceed.

```
.table {
     table-layout: fixed; 
     width: 100%;
}
```

I tried to edit the td1, td2, but I think I need to change the  inside the td to achive what I want, but all I tried did nothing.

[My List, for examples see #51,#58 in Completed](http://myanimelist.net/animelist/ErgoCanis)

Thanks for helping me, sorry for my bad english and if you need other informations I'll try to provide it to you.

solution (worked for me)

```
td.td2 span, td.td1 span { 
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.td1, .td2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px !important;
    max-width: 416px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may need text-overflow and turn span as a box :

`td.td2 span {
display:block;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}`

---

```css
td.td2 span {
display:block;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td2" style="border-left-width: 1px;" align="center" width="30">28</td>
        <td class="td2" style="border-left-width: 0">
            <div style="float: right;"> 
              <small>
         <a href="/panel.php?go=add&amp;selected_series_id=27899&amp;hidenav=true" class="List_LightBox">Add</a> - 
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="xmenu27899" onclick="getExpand(27899,2);" title="View More Information">More</a>
  </small>

            </div> 
          <small  style="float: right;margin:0.25em;">Airing</small> 
          <a href="/anime/27899/Tokyo_Ghoul_√A" target="_blank" class="animetitle" title="Anime Information"><span>Tokyo Ghoul √A</span></a> 
        </td>
        <td class="td2" align="center" width="45">5</td>
        <td class="td2" align="center" width="50">TV</td>
        <td class="td2" align="center" width="70">8/12</td>
        <td class="td2" align="left" width="125"> <span id="tagLinks27899"><a href="/animelist/ErgoCanis&amp;tag=Studio Pierrot&amp;status=7">Studio Pierrot</a></span>
 <span id="tagRow27899" style="display: none;">Studio Pierrot</span>
        </td>
        <td class="td2" align="center" nowrap="" width="75"><span title=""> &nbsp; </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a problem 

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150314/5326iaqu.png

my actual code:

`td.td2 span, td.td1 span {
display:block;  
white-space:nowrap;  
overflow:hidden;  
text-overflow:ellipsis;  
}`

Comment: @StevenOrthey what about the HTML involved Here, table cols do not break from a line to another unless colspan used or display is  reset

Comment: I marked the section you mentioned? Sorry I still have my problems reading the code of other websites.

http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150314/9uo77nfh.jpg

I just don't unterstand why only some rows break it and others not.

Thanks

Comment: @StevenOrthey okay i see, it breaks cause you do not have a single table, but many stacked on each others, that is why the columns can break, if you remave the </table><table> tags in between each rows (<tr>) it will behave as a single column all the way down :)

Comment: How? Its not my website can I stil change it? There is also problem with the other categorys: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150314/2xkp5w6n.jpg

I also updates the main post with the whole css file

Sorry About the many dumb questions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StevenOrthey to force you tds to be all same width, you can use : table {
table-layout:fixed;
} and then set a width to your tds, then will not expand their width over the width specified anymore

Comment: I still have this problem:
fs1.directupload.net/images/150314/2xkp5w6n.jpg 

The reason is the display:block; If I comment it out the other tables (watching, ...) are normal, but then i can't truncate it

Comment: @StevenOrthey okay, so table-layout :fixed on table + white-space,overflow,text-overflow straigth to .td2 should work if div is not floatting but turned into inline or inline-block

Comment: @StevenOrthey actually, forget my previous comment, it would best to set the <small>airing</small> before the <span> in the html and float the <small> right.

Comment: @StevenOrthey I added a snippet to my answer to show what i mean

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the html so this is out of option

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing more of the code, I can only venture a guess as to what you want - you could try setting a height and max width for your `<td>` and using

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

See [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aqfh9jf2/1/)

**EDIT:**
GCyrillus added `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to the solution, and I hadn't even thought of it - it's a good way to make the text look neater. Updated [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aqfh9jf2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
td.td2 span { 
   display:block; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: did you notice my answer an hour ago ?